# Debian, ActiveDirectory and Password

Tags: debian, password, active-directory

I have joined a Debian Wheezy to a Win server 2003 with Active Directory, following [this guide](https://wiki.debian.org/AuthenticatingLinuxWithActiveDirectory):

Everything goes well except for the password change. I am not able to change the password of my domain user. When I try (with `passwd` or at `logon`) the system tells me that there is a *kerberos ticket problem*.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debian, Active Directory and password change](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156393/debian-active-directory-and-password-change)

Comment: Please do not post questions multiple times.